# Fixing position on DIV while page scrolls

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, position

I have a page with 2 columns. The left column is quite longer than the right one.

When I start scrolling I'd like the right column to stay where it is so only the left column moves.

This means the right column will always be visible when the page is scrolled.

I thought I needed to set the div as `position:fixed;`  This works but moves the right div so it sits over the left.

How do I do this properly so the right div stays in place?

[I've created a fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wzzopxte/2/)

I've also looked at using jquery to animate the scrolling, but that didn't work either..

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $("#right").stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px", "marginLeft":($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"}, "slow" );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `position: fixed` on the `#right` div

CSS

```
#right {
    width: auto;
    float: right;
    top: 40px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    position: fixed;
}
```

DEMO

https://jsfiddle.net/wzzopxte/5/

Comment: The works, until I add a horizontal menu and wrapper to the page. Then the div starts ate 40px from the top of the page and not from `list`

Answer (score 0):

it works with `position:fixed;` on the `#right_container` but you also have to set `right:0;`

i also used percentages instead of fixed widths on the containers. it's much more responsive and prevents the divs from overlapping because of the `position:fixed` but if you really need fixed widths...you can use them but keep in mind that there are some side-effects

see code snippet below. let me know if it helps

```css
body {
 font-family: arial;
 margin: 0px;
}

.drag {
 cursor: move;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 10pt;
 opacity: 0.7;
 width: 120px;
 min-height: 24px;
 line-height: 24px;
 border: 2px solid #800000;
}


#drag {
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 display: table;
    position: relative;
 border: 1px solid #d9a300;
}

.list {
 border: 1px solid #00b359;
 min-height: 350px;
    display: table;
 width: 100%;
}


#left_container {
 width: 63%;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 2%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #F6F6F6;
 border: 1px solid #ff26ff;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#left {
 width: 100%;
 display: table-cell;
 border: 1px solid #2d00b3;
}


#right_container {
 width: 33%;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 2%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #F6F6F6;
 border: 1px solid #ffff00;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;


}

#right {
 width: auto;
 float: right;
 top: 40px;
 background-color: #eee;
 border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;


  
 
}
```

```html
<div id="drag">

 <fieldset><legend><b>TITLE</legend>
 <div class='list'>
  
  <!-- left container -->
  <div id="left_container">
  
   <div id="left">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis eget erat non augue vestibulum fringilla. Maecenas fermentum ante mattis interdum vestibulum. Aliquam vel dui ac turpis consectetur accumsan quis eu libero. Sed finibus neque vel ipsum lacinia lobortis. Pellentesque lorem erat, ullamcorper vitae consectetur nec, tempor sit amet nisi. Aenean posuere ante egestas quam rhoncus, ut laoreet dui mattis. Quisque condimentum fermentum metus sit amet posuere. Ut sed lectus orci.
   Cras nec enim faucibus, consectetur eros ut, vulputate est. Maecenas sollicitudin vestibulum eros, sit amet porta enim molestie eget. Etiam commodo ex efficitur ligula ornare iaculis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam mollis eleifend nisl a rhoncus. Sed egestas lacinia est ut mollis. Duis fermentum odio eget diam placerat, eu placerat sapien laoreet. Sed mollis leo id tortor dapibus, in finibus lacus aliquet. Donec semper vel libero eu placerat. Nam hendrerit pretium nunc, vel malesuada nisi tincidunt in. Duis ligula metus, dignissim ac laoreet in, aliquam et ipsum. Maecenas non condimentum leo. Morbi convallis turpis lobortis dignissim mattis.
   Quisque at hendrerit magna. Praesent id ligula eleifend, semper lacus sed, sagittis mauris. Nulla molestie tristique sem, non ultrices nisl mattis ut. Nulla ut nisi quis elit porta tempor. Duis semper sem tellus, nec viverra metus dignissim nec. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla libero lectus, iaculis sit amet enim eget, facilisis blandit enim. Ut dolor massa, imperdiet id lorem a, molestie vestibulum nulla. Fusce non condimentum purus, ut egestas mi. Ut lacinia rutrum nulla a convallis. Vestibulum ac metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In ac eleifend mi.
   Duis at cursus mauris, non viverra ipsum. Sed facilisis, arcu eu aliquam volutpat, nisi leo interdum neque, in congue libero purus a eros. Pellentesque posuere tellus ut consequat dapibus. Ut dapibus ultrices sem, in posuere eros. Aliquam tincidunt, arcu a dignissim eleifend, urna diam pulvinar urna, non hendrerit lorem urna ac nibh. Cras eu feugiat enim. Aliquam ornare sapien non orci pellentesque, ac pretium felis finibus.
   Suspendisse potenti. Cras placerat lorem quis purus facilisis pretium. Ut blandit vehicula erat, eget rutrum elit tempus vitae. Nulla placerat aliquet consequat. Phasellus tempus odio et augue congue venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In gravida, odio vitae porttitor gravida, est elit imperdiet orci, nec pretium lectus risus vitae purus. Aenean dictum nisi a orci aliquet, et scelerisque tortor tincidunt.
  </div>    
  
  </div><!-- left container -->
   
  <!-- right container -->
  <div id="right_container">
   <div id="right">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed velit metus, euismod quis ante eleifend, tempor euismod turpis. Suspendisse a euismod nibh, nec viverra ipsum. Sed ullamcorper eros in nisi condimentum rhoncus. Nunc suscipit interdum ligula vel tempus. Donec tortor libero, gravida a condimentum at, lobortis at nibh. Pellentesque habitant.
   </div>
  </div>
   
  </div><!--- list --->
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this (comments in the code to what I have changed)

```js
var right = $("#right_container"); // get your right container

$(window).scroll(function() {
  right.css("top", $(this).scrollTop()); // change it's top position - don't need to use animate otherwise it will be too slow
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0px;
}
.drag {
  cursor: move;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10pt;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 120px;
  min-height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #800000;
}
#drag {
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #d9a300;
}
.list {
  border: 1px solid #00b359;
  min-height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /* make this relative and not a table */
}
#left_container {
  /* remove float left */
  width: 450px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F6F6F6;
  border: 1px solid #ff26ff;
}
#left {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #2d00b3;
}
#right_container {
  position: absolute;
  /* remove float right and position this absolutely, remove margin right */
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  right: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F6F6F6;
  border: 1px solid #ffff00;
}
#right {
  width: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drag">

  <fieldset>
    <legend>TITLE</legend>
 <div class='list'>

  <!-- left container -->
  <div id="left_container">
  
   <div id="left">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis eget erat non augue vestibulum fringilla. Maecenas fermentum ante mattis interdum vestibulum. Aliquam vel dui ac turpis consectetur accumsan quis eu libero. Sed finibus neque vel ipsum lacinia lobortis. Pellentesque lorem erat, ullamcorper vitae consectetur nec, tempor sit amet nisi. Aenean posuere ante egestas quam rhoncus, ut laoreet dui mattis. Quisque condimentum fermentum metus sit amet posuere. Ut sed lectus orci.
   Cras nec enim faucibus, consectetur eros ut, vulputate est. Maecenas sollicitudin vestibulum eros, sit amet porta enim molestie eget. Etiam commodo ex efficitur ligula ornare iaculis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam mollis eleifend nisl a rhoncus. Sed egestas lacinia est ut mollis. Duis fermentum odio eget diam placerat, eu placerat sapien laoreet. Sed mollis leo id tortor dapibus, in finibus lacus aliquet. Donec semper vel libero eu placerat. Nam hendrerit pretium nunc, vel malesuada nisi tincidunt in. Duis ligula metus, dignissim ac laoreet in, aliquam et ipsum. Maecenas non condimentum leo. Morbi convallis turpis lobortis dignissim mattis.
   Quisque at hendrerit magna. Praesent id ligula eleifend, semper lacus sed, sagittis mauris. Nulla molestie tristique sem, non ultrices nisl mattis ut. Nulla ut nisi quis elit porta tempor. Duis semper sem tellus, nec viverra metus dignissim nec. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla libero lectus, iaculis sit amet enim eget, facilisis blandit enim. Ut dolor massa, imperdiet id lorem a, molestie vestibulum nulla. Fusce non condimentum purus, ut egestas mi. Ut lacinia rutrum nulla a convallis. Vestibulum ac metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In ac eleifend mi.
   Duis at cursus mauris, non viverra ipsum. Sed facilisis, arcu eu aliquam volutpat, nisi leo interdum neque, in congue libero purus a eros. Pellentesque posuere tellus ut consequat dapibus. Ut dapibus ultrices sem, in posuere eros. Aliquam tincidunt, arcu a dignissim eleifend, urna diam pulvinar urna, non hendrerit lorem urna ac nibh. Cras eu feugiat enim. Aliquam ornare sapien non orci pellentesque, ac pretium felis finibus.
   Suspendisse potenti. Cras placerat lorem quis purus facilisis pretium. Ut blandit vehicula erat, eget rutrum elit tempus vitae. Nulla placerat aliquet consequat. Phasellus tempus odio et augue congue venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In gravida, odio vitae porttitor gravida, est elit imperdiet orci, nec pretium lectus risus vitae purus. Aenean dictum nisi a orci aliquet, et scelerisque tortor tincidunt.
  </div>    
  
  </div><!-- left container -->
   
  <!-- right container -->
  <div id="right_container">
   <div id="right">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed velit metus, euismod quis ante eleifend, tempor euismod turpis. Suspendisse a euismod nibh, nec viverra ipsum. Sed ullamcorper eros in nisi condimentum rhoncus. Nunc suscipit interdum ligula vel tempus. Donec tortor libero, gravida a condimentum at, lobortis at nibh. Pellentesque habitant.
   </div>
  </div>
   
  </div><!--- list --->
    </fieldset>
</div>
```